# How can I resolve the 'invalid object where a stream was expected' error when uploading CSV files using Angular post API?

Tags: javascript, angular

When upload csv file in post API so getting this error.
**You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

Angular version - 11.2.14
RXJS - ~6.5.4

uploadCSV.service.ts

```
previewResearch(data) {
    let fd: FormData = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file.filename);
    return this.httpService.post("API PATH", fd)
}
```

http.service.ts

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, body);
}
```

**You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**